# How do I get the "left-most 128 bits of a byte array"?

Tags: c#, cryptography, openid-connect

So I'm reading through the JWT token format as described at Open ID Connect and one of the fields (at_hash) says that it is the left-most 128 bits of hash made from the oauth access token. So what I've done is taken the token, hashed it, and then attempted to pull the "left-most" 128 bits out, but I feel like I'm doing this all wrong; it feels kludgy.

So I guess my questions are:

- Is this even remoted correct?
- Is there a better, more accurate way to do this?

  ```
  private byte[] GetFirst128(byte[] hash)
  {
      var bitArray = new BitArray(hash);
      var left128 = new List<bool>();
      for (var i = 0; i < 128; i++)
      {
          left128.Add(bitArray[i]);
      }

      // convert back to byte[]
      var r = Array.ConvertAll(left128.ToArray(),
          bit => bit
              ? (byte) 1
              : (byte) 0);

      return r;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

128 bits is 16 bytes, so you could just do:

```
hash.Take(16).ToArray();
```

Comment: This is the most appropriate solution. You could also define constants if you don't want the hassle of having to find this one line to modify if it changes to 256 bits (32 bytes) etc.

Comment: sweet. I knew I over-complicated it.